# UnexpectedNullableFound on left (self) join on aliased table

Tags: anorm

I am having a simple employee table, which has manager_id by which it can refer it self. I am trying to get an employee along with his manager

Here are my Parsers

```
object User{

  val simple = {
   get[Option[Int]]("users.user_id")~
   str("users.email")~
   get[Option[String]]("users.first_name")~
   get[Option[String]]("users.last_name")~
   get[Option[String]]("users.nick_name")~
   bool("users.is_manager")~
   bool("users.is_hr_manager")~
   bool("users.is_admin")~
   get[Option[Int]]("users.manager_id") map {
    case user_id~email~first_name~last_name~nick_name~is_manager~is_hr_manager~is_admin~manager_id  => {
        User(user_id,email,first_name,last_name,nick_name,is_manager,is_hr_manager,is_admin,manager_id)
      }
    }
  }

  def getAliasedParser(alias:String):RowParser[User] = {
     getAliased[Option[Int]](alias+"_user_id")~
     getAliased[String](alias+"_email")~
     getAliased[Option[String]](alias+"_first_name")~
     getAliased[Option[String]](alias+"_last_name")~
     getAliased[Option[String]](alias+"_nick_name")~
     getAliased[Boolean](alias+"_is_manager")~
     getAliased[Boolean](alias+"_is_hr_manager")~
     getAliased[Boolean](alias+"_is_admin")~
     getAliased[Option[Int]](alias+"_manager_id") map {
      case user_id~email~first_name~last_name~nick_name~is_manager~is_hr_manager~is_admin~manager_id  => {
          User(user_id,email,first_name,last_name,nick_name,is_manager,is_hr_manager,is_admin,manager_id)
        }
      }
  }

 val withManager = User.simple ~ (User.getAliasedParser("mgr") ?) map {
    case user~manager => (user,manager)
  }
```

UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(users.email,Some(mgr_email)))]

Here is my query:

```
def findByEmailWithManager(email: String): Option[(User,Option[User])] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("""
          SELECT 
          `users`.`user_id`,
          `users`.`email`,    
          `users`.`first_name`,     
          `users`.`last_name`,    
          `users`.`nick_name`,    
          `users`.`is_manager`,     
          `users`.`is_hr_manager`,    
          `users`.`is_admin`,    
          `users`.`manager_id` ,
          b.`user_id` mgr_user_id,
          b.`email` mgr_email,    
          b.`first_name` mgr_first_name,     
          b.`last_name` mgr_last_name,    
          b.`nick_name` mgr_nick_name,    
          b.`is_manager` mgr_is_manager,     
          b.`is_hr_manager` mgr_is_hr_manager,    
          b.`is_admin` mgr_is_admin,    
          b.`manager_id` mgr_manager_id
          FROM `users` left outer join `users` b on (users.manager_id = b.user_id)
          where `users`.email = {email}
          """).on('email -> email).as(User.withManager.singleOpt)
    }
  }
```

I get this error when I try execute the query

```
UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(users.email,Some(mgr_email)))]
```

Here is my case class

```
case class User(id:Option[Int]=None,email:String,firstName:Option[String]=None,lastName:Option[String]=None,nickName:Option[String]=None,isManager:Boolean=false,isHrManager:Boolean=false,isAdministrator:Boolean=false,managerId:Option[Int]=None)
```

Could someone help me understand why i get this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: The column is `NULL` whereas not optional in the parser. You should execute the query by hand with same parameter to check the parsed column, and possibly update the parsing by making it optional.

Comment: I am using a self join here, so the right side can be null completely. Does that mean that i have to define all the mappings of right side as optional? Then what is the point of adding question mark after (User.getAliasedParser("mgr") ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All column that can be null need to be parsed as option: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#working-with-optionalnullable-columns